# Holding session when using Instagram with puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I tried using puppeteer to log in to Instagram. I logged in, but somehow sessionid is not set to cookie and I cannot see followers and followings. To be exact, the login screen is repeated because sessionid is not set. How is the sessionid set in the cookie?

```
async function () {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        args: [
            '--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'
        ]
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    const response = await page.goto(loginUrl, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
    await page.setViewport({
        width: 1200,
        height: 800,
    });

    let usrElm = await page.type('input[name="username"]', 'username');
    let passElm = await page.type('input[name="password"]', 'password');
    await page.click('button[type="submit"]');  //login success

    await page.goto(followersUrl, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' }); 
    //Return to the login screen. sessionid is not set.

    await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: You have to waitForSelector or waitForFunction before doing some `goto` function there. You have to check the login process works successfully, maybe by checking if your username is displayed on the page after login.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you don't give a chance for Instagram to finish the logging in process. You can quickly solve it by adding `waitForNavigation()` before the click.

It's nicely described in the documentation https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageclickselector-options

But you should also verify whether you're logged in or not. Otherwise, it might unexpected fail. There're several ways to do that but I think the best solution would be to check if `sessionId` exists in cookies.